# How to connect database to my website

Tags: database

I have a project asking me to develop a database along with a website user interface, but I only know how to create the database and how to connect the database using JDBC. What should I learn to achieve connecting a website to the database and do some interactions? Should I use JavaScript, PHP, or embed JDBC code into the HTML code? Please tell me where I should start for this project.

I am using Oracle 10g, I know how to connect database via JDBC, but the part I need help is how to create a website interface instead of a java application interface.

Comment: We need to know a lot more to make any kind of recommendation. What platform? What language? What database? The more details you give, the more helpful the answers.

Comment: @meager - I think he **asks** what language to use.

Comment: ..But please do tell us your constrains, if there are any.. Is .NET an option? Or only php and Java?

Comment: meagar is correct -- but for a generic answer, most people generally do JDBC-calls (or similar) from a server-side language (Java, C#, etc).  Thus, your website would pass the user's requests to the server, the server would query the DB and then return the results, the website would render the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

baboon:  it seems (to me) that for your prof. to just hand you a project to "develop a web app" -- without providing you any kind of basic lecture on how to go about it -- is a bit of a steep task.  You not only have to learn about servlets and web-containers and WARs, but the MVC-approach most good java-web-frameworks use can present a fairly steep learning-curve the first time you are introduced to them.  You may want to check with your prof. to make sure you understand the requirements -- usually this sort of project would be the culmination of an entire semester's worth of lectures, wherein the instructor would have presented you with all of the big tools you'd need to accomplish this task.

Nevertheless, I recommend you develop it using the Spring platform.

Here is a simple "Hello World" tutorial -- there may be better ones out there, but I recall having done this one a while back and it seemed to be pretty good.  http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring

Note:  the Spring framework is a Java development framework that does many things.  One of the things that it's commonly used for is writing a web-app using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague. You didn't mention what database you're using. Also, since you mentioned JDBC, I'll assume you're using Java. You cannot "embed" JDBC code into html. Using JSP you can do this, but it's not recommended. Forget about connecting to a database using Javascript because it's a client side technology.

For starters, find a JDBC tutorial. There are many of these on the net, so google one up. Also, you'll need a JDBC driver for your particular database. After you managed to get that part working, you can focus on making a website user interface. But that's a different story...

**Edit**: ok, you're using JDBC and Oracle 10g.

You've chosen a technology to connect to a database and you have a database.

First of all, JDBC stands for Java DataBase Connectivity. That means you have to use Java to connect to a database.

You'll need Oracle's JDBC driver to connect to Oracle's database using Java. I'll assume you've dealt with these parts.

Next, you'll need a Java application server, or at least a servlet container. I recommend you try out [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

After you've chosen one, study its tutorials on how to set it up. Specifically, how to use it to connect to your database and how to access the admin page.

When that is done, choose a view technology for creating your web interface. JSP (Java Server Pages) is one of the oldest view technologies, and the simplest one, so you may start out with that. It will generate HTML code that allows your web site users to access it and user your web interface.

There's a lot of stuff going on here just to make a simple website that will also use database connectivity. Try googling any unknown terms I have introduced or search them at Stackoverflow. I wish you best of luck!